# How to apply Ljung Box Test?

Tags: time-series, finance, econometrics, random-walk

I am checking the closing prices(about 9000+ prices) of the stocks data to test for randomness.

The test I am using is Ljung Box test, in MFE toolbox for MATLAB,

I used 300 data of closing prices, and 8 lags.
Q = test statistics.
pval = pvalue.

[Q, pval] = ljungbox(closingPrices,lags);

However, no matter which 30 intervals of 300, I keep getting all the p-value as zero, meaning, reject null hypothesis and conclude that there is no serial correlation.

i tried with different types of stocks, but all the p-value are all zero, which made the Ljung Box's test not very interesting.

May i know if I had used the Ljung Box Test wrongly?

If you have any comments, please enlighten me, thank you very much.

Comment: I'd advise against Ljung-Box test for financial data. It has terrible size properties.

Comment: Try using price returns and maybe look at lmtest since the returns are most likely heteroskedastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ljung-Box [test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test), the null hypothesis is:

$H_0$: ***The data are independently distributed***

So, your p-values of 0 indeed indicate that you should reject the null hypothesis, but it means that your data is ***not*** independently distributed, and in particular that there is some significant autocorrelation in the process.

**This is obviously the case, because you use prices!!!** The price at time $t_{i+1}$ clearly depends of the price at time $t_i$.

In order to have an interesting result, you need to test the returns of the price series, as opposed to the prices themselves.

Comment: May I ask, how do you get the returns of the price series from the closing prices of the stocks for each trade window. For examples there are weekly prices, $27, $29, $30, $26 for march, and $31, $29, $30, $28 for April.

So the returns of the price series for march is (2, 3, -1) with 1 lag, and for April it is (2, -1, -3) with 1 lag?

Comment: Actually, you may not really ask this on this site as it is dedicated to professional quants or academics (see the [faq]), but the return $r_t$ is defined as $r_t=\frac{p_t}{r_{p-1}}-1$.